# Cannot install Visual Studio C# NuGet package

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm writing a Unity app, and i keep experiencing game engine freeze when I use LoadImage on a large JPG, so i decide to try to decode the JPG image on a thread (so as not to freeze the main thread by decoding the JPG on the main thread which is my theory as to why the freeze is happenning).

The plan is, after the thread decodes the JPG, use the main thread to call  LoadRawImageData to load the decoded image data into a texture, which should be fast since it doesnt have to decode anything.

To do all that i need to find a JPG decoder package, so in the Visual Studio NuGet package manager i saw the package "LibJpeg.NET" which claims to have no dependencies,  but when i try to install the package in my Visual Studio Unity project which uses .Net 3.5 i get the Nuget error

> Could not install package 'LibJpeg.NET-ts 2.0.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v3.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Anybody knows how to solve this, or maybe anybody knows another free .NET 3.5 compatible cross platform (Windows/Mac/iOS/Android) JPEG decoder package i can use on a thread in Unity to decode a JPG?

Comment: You could look at ImageMagick packages - i remember using them 10 years ago

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the [nuget package page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Portable.LibJpeg.NET/), it says that you cannot install it if your application targets any version lower than .Net framework 4.

> Supported platforms .NET 4 and higher, Windows 8 and higher, Windows
> Phone Silverlight 8 and 8.1, Windows Phone 8.1 and higher, Silverlight
> 5, Xamarin Android, Xamarin iOS (Classic and Unified API). The package
> also includes an assembly for .NET Core, Standard Library 1.0.

If you want your project to be used on windows / linux / max, then it should be targetting to .net standard (i.e. .Net core ) version.

Once you target to .net standard, you would be either able to use same package or you would be able to use some other libraries e.g.
[BitMiracle.LibJpeg.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BitMiracle.LibJpeg.NET/) OR  [libjpeg-turbo-net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/libjpeg-turbo-net/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: oh right, i see that now. Thanks! So a unity app can target the .net standard also?

Comment: If you pick an older version of the library, there are no dependencies, so just select an older version in the nuget browser such as 1.5.0.1

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but Its very strange that it only shows version 2.0.1, no other version is shown in the NUGET dialog box for libjpeg.net

Comment: Unity targets to .net core.  Please refer this blog for more details - http://loekvandenouweland.com/content/unity-dot-net-standard-dot-net-core.html

Comment: Sounds like you might be using a different one, looking on google there are several. If you go to the nuget webpage for the one you are using, you can click the older versions and expand 'dependencies' to see if you can find one that you can meet the dependency criteria of. You can force that version to install by using the command line parameter even if it's not in the nuget package manager.

Comment: [.NET Framework 4.7.2 conforms to .NET Standard 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#latest-target-framework-versions) also, not just .NET Core. so you may want to remove the "(i.e. .Net core framework)"...